# How to set the image of row RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android

I need to set the image of my  row RecyclerView how to add the image of employee I want to convert the String to Bitmap and display the image in an imageView

Activity 1

```
 String name = currentobject.getString("name_related");
                    String email = currentobject.getString("work_email");
                    String phone = currentobject.getString("work_phone");
                    String Img = currentobject.getString("image_small");
                    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(Img.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
```

employee= new Employee(id,(String)deptArry.get(1),email,phone,decodedByte.toString(),name);
                        Employees.add(employee);

ClassAdapter how to add the image of employee

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(EmployeeHolder holder, int position) {
            Employee employee=EmployeeList.get(position);
            holder.id.setText(employee.getId());
            holder.name.setText(employee.getName());
            holder.phone.setText(employee.getPhone());
            holder.Image.set????(employee.getImage());

    }
```

Employee object with getter and setter ...

```
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String Image;
```

Comment: If I get you right, you might want to use ImageView in the viewholder.
In addition to that you might want to use a library to convert string to image like http://jcraane.blogspot.com/2009/01/text-image-generator-example.html
Then you can do somehting like ImageView.setImageBitmap()

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewHolder should have an ImageView as part of it's layout.  Right now you are trying to set the image on "Image", but "Image" is type String. 
 Once you have an ImageView as part of your layout then you can simply call:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte)
```

Comment: holder.email.setText(employee.getEmail());
        holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(employee.getImage()); 
dosen't work

Comment: Sorry, you would still need to convert the image string to a Bitmap.  If I understand correctly your employee.getImage() method would return a String, and then you need to convert that to Bitmap and set it inside holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap.

Comment: String Img = currentobject.getString("image_small");
                        byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(Img.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);

Comment: employee= new Employee(decodedByte);
                        Employees.add(employee);

Comment: and my class adapter 
public void onBindViewHolder
        holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(employee.getImage());

Comment: So you're not getting an error, the image just isn't showing up in your recyclerview row?  But the rest of your fields show up in the recyclerview row?